# Get-MailboxFolderStatistics ItemsInFolder also returns subfolder counts and counts are not correct

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm using PowerShell to return a report of Exchange mailbox statistics as a tab-delimited text file.  I'm having trouble with the `ItemsInFolder` property of the `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` cmdlet (from the Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.e2010 snapin).  If I run it against a mailbox like this:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics myusername -FolderScope Inbox | Select ItemsInFolder
```

it yields the following:

```
ItemsInFolder
-------------
          556
```

but the count in the inbox folder as viewed through Outlook is **513**.  I found [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996762%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)  that has a note that says

> A mailbox can have hidden items that are never visible to the user and are only used by applications. The Get-MailboxFolderStatistics cmdlet can return hidden items for the following values: FolderSize, FolderAndSubfolderSize, ItemsInFolder, and ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders.

but I fairly certain this folder doesn't have any hidden items.  Also, if I add a folder beneath the Inbox and move some items into it then run the cmdlet again, it reports the counts for BOTH folders:

```
ItemsInFolder
-------------
          547
           11
```

it's my understanding that the `ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders` property was supposed to return counts for sub-folders, not the `ItemsInFolder` property.  So here are my questions:

1. how do I get the cmdlet to return values for only the root folder provided, and
2. how do I get it to return only items that are visible to the user?

Comment: fixed (thanks for asking this)

Comment: Is this a shared mailbox? If so, items marked as "private" may not be visible to other users and hence be "hidden". Also, there may potentially be a large number of hidden system items (e.g. to do with custom views for the folder, etc.) and dumpster items. Back in my Exchange Admin days I used to use tools like MFCMAPI to troubleshoot issues such as this.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of your current command, run this command, and look for the appropriate property/value pair in the command's output.

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics myusername -FolderScope Inbox | Select-Object -Property *;
```

That will retrieve all of the properties on the object, and allow you to find the appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks Trevor; this is very useful.  I used it to figure out how to exclude the sub-folders from my query, but I still can't figure out how to exclude hidden items.

Comment: Sadly, the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.management.tasks.mailboxfolderconfiguration_properties(v=exchg.150).aspx) that lists these properties doesn't have any description details for each property... Shame.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt you can always pipe it to Get-Member to grab the available properties/methods etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to the first part of my question (how to return values for only the root, i.e. "Inbox"): add `| Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Inbox"}` to the call, as in:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics myusername -FolderScope Inbox | Select ItemsInFolder | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Inbox"}
```

Comment: I think you need to swap the `Select` and `Where-Object` around in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Roryap, for the inbox folder statistics you should run:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity myusername -FolderScope Inbox | ?{$_.FolderPath -like '/Inbox'} | Select Name, ItemsInFolder
```

That will first get the values for the mailbox, then filter to only top 'Inbox' folder (sometimes you can have other Inbox folders in other location ie for ipfx app), finally get the name and itemsInFolder.

Unfortunately that is not resolving the case of numbers being different in outlook and coming from the PS :(

Answer (score 0):

If the `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` cmdlet fails to distinguish between hidden and normal items, you might want to try "looking" at the folder via a mail client. I lifted most of the code below from [another website](https://smtpport25.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/powershell-to-get-the-number-of-mails-in-the-inbox-and-number-of-unread-emails-in-inbox/):

```
$Outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$Session = $Outlook.Session
$Session.Logon()
$Inbox = $Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$ItemCount = @(%{$Inbox.Items}).Count
$UnreadCount = @(%{$Inbox.Items | ?{$_.Unread}}).Count

[PSCustomObject]@{"Items"=$ItemCount;"Unread"=$UnreadCount}
```

I guess there is a version of doing this using Exchange Web Services too, but the basic idea is that if you want to see the mailbox like the end user does, access it via a mail client rather than query the mailbox store.